# In Java 7 or below, HOWTO filter a list of map objects using key/value found in the map

Tags: java, collections, underscore.js, guava, lambda

I have a list of map objects. These map objects have properties/keys like id, condition_1, condition_2 etc. A sample map looks like so,

```
List<Map<String, Object>> allItems = Lists.newArrayList();

Map<String, Object> paramsMap = Maps.newHashMap();

paramsMap.put("id", "a");
paramsMap.put("condition_1", false);
paramsMap.put("condition_2", true);
paramsMap.put("condition_3", false);

allItems.add(paramsMap);
```

So, I need to filter the `allItems` object such that it has only those map objects which have `condition_1 = true` & `condition_2 = false`, & so on & so forth.

I thought about using apache commons [CollectionUtils.filter](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#filter(java.lang.Iterable,%20org.apache.commons.collections4.Predicate)) but that doesn't seem to solve my problem because I have no way of specifying map entries as filter conditions.

I am not averse to using Google Guava as well, but I was unable to find a good solution.

Basically I am trying to mimic the [`_.where`](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#where) functionality found in the excellent JavaScript library underscore.js.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One Guava solution:

```
Iterables.filter(allItems, new Predicate<Map<String, Object>>() {
   @Override public boolean apply(Map<String, Object> map) {
      return Boolean.TRUE.equals(map.get("condition_1"))
         && Boolean.FALSE.equals(map.get("condition_2"));
   }
});
```

Comment: BTW this works the same as the common-collections `CollectionUtils.filter` mentioned in the question.

Comment: @ShawnBush: Not quite; that removes elements, while this returns a view.

Comment: Good point; my comment wasn't worded clearly. I meant that in terms of what the question was asking for, both would work as a solution. But maybe I missed some aspect of the question.

Comment: @ShawnBush re: CollectionUtils.filter, I was not able to create a Predicate which accepts Map<String, Object> as an input & use that to filter it. But as Louis mentioned I wouldn't be able to use it anyways, since it modifies the original colledction, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: @Chantz Oh I see, you were using a pre-4.0 version of commons-collections, which means it didn't have support for Generics. I also missed the point about not modifying the original collection in your question. Guava is better anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to do this the long way. Unfortunately Java Maps are not of type Iterable which means most common libraries don't have filter functions for them. Try something like this (I believe strings are implicitly true in java in case you are worried about your first key-value pair):

```

```
boolean result = true;
boolean test = true;
List<Map<String, Object> resultList;
for(Map<String, Object> map : allitems) {
    for(String key : map.keySet()) {
        result = result && test && map.get(key);
        test = !test;
    }
    if(result) { 
        resultList.add(map); 
    }
} 
return resultList;
```

```

Another possibility is to turn your Map into a List of [`KeyValue`s](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/KeyValue.html) and using apache mapping and list functions. Most likely, while you are using java 7, you are not going to get that pretty one liner. Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks @laazer but I will go with Louis solution that incolves use of Guava.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to actually do the same what Kotlin does in method `Map<K, V>.filter`.

Let's create predicate:

```
public interface Predicate<T> {
    boolean apply(T t);
}
```

Predicate is an interface useful for functional-like programming. Method apply returns true when a condition is fulfilled.

Then, create class like `CollectionUtils` and put a static method there:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> filter(
    @NonNull Map<K, V> collection,
    @NonNull Predicate<Map.Entry<K, V>> predicate
) {
    Map<K, V> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : collection.entrySet()) {
        if (predicate.apply(entry) {
            result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This way we can use this method in following way:

```
Map<String, Object> map = ...;
Map<String, Object> filtered = CollectionUtils.filter(map, new Predicate<Map.Entry<String, Object>>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry) {
        return isEntryOK(entry);
    }
};
```

If you in fact can use Java 8, but because of some reasons you cannot use Java's streams (like Android Development supporting older version of Android not compatible with Java 8) you can remove syntax's sugger and write it in better form:

```
Map<String, Object> map = ...;
Map<String, Object> filtered = CollectionUtils.filter(
    map,
    entry -> isEntryOK(entry)
);
```

Or, the best solution in my opinion -> **Switch to Kotlin which gives you all those features out of the box! :D**

Answer (score -4):

in Java 8 you could use streams:

```
allItems.stream()
        .filter(map->
        (map.get("condition_1")==true)&&(map.get("condition_2")==false))
        .forEach(System.out::println); //Example output
```

Comment: Ok, Unfortunately I am not using Java 8 :(